# Значение аргумента по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Нужно передать аргумент по ссылке, например, так:

```
Сlass Foo;
Class Bar{
    ...
    void func(Foo& f = NULL){
    if (f != NULL)
      {
       ...
      }
    }
};
```

Передать указатель на Foo не получается из-за существующего интерфейса.
Поменять интерфейс не могу, что делать?

Comment: Вышеприведенный код не сильно похож на с++. Можете написать минимальный пример, который воспроизводит Вашу проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интерфейс не корректен. Ссылка (`&`) требует существования объекта, и её нельзя задать нулем (`NULL`), который используется для указателей. Нужно или заменить ссылку на указатель в интерфейсе

```
func(Foo* f = NULL){...}
```

или уйти от некорректных сопоставлений с нулём (`NULL`).

Можно ещё переопределить макрос `NULL` на что-то, возвращающее ссылку на структуру, которая понимается "нулевой ссылкой". Но это муть и очевидное извращение, до добра не доведёт. Однако, и это можно сделать (но лучше, конечно же, не делать):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

#define NULL_ORIG NULL
#undef NULL
#define NULL getNullFoo()

// для примера, вы не привели, как у вас объявлен класс Foo
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

// Тоже для примера, логику "неравенства" двух объектов Foo определять лучше вам
bool operator!=(const Foo & one, const Foo & another)
{
    if(one.a != another.a) return true;
    return false;
}

Foo & getNullFoo()
{
    // какой-то статический объект, который принимается за "нулевой"
    static Foo result(-1);
    return result;
}

void func(Foo& f = NULL){
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Not null Foo" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Null Foo" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo someFoo(1);
    func(someFoo);
    func(NULL);
// больше переопределенный NULL не нужен, восстанавливаем
#define NULL NULL_ORIG
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду просить поменять интерфейс на нормальный.